# How to test whether a random variable is well simulated

Tags: r, simulation

Suppose I write my version of ‘rnorm’ function,then I generate 10000 numbers by this function.So,how to test whether this random variable is well simulated?
I guess that ‘ecdf’ then ‘plot’ would be fine.Maybe density plot is fine?The method above I mentioned is fine?Any other way?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you elaborate on what "well simulated" might mean?  This issue can cover a lot of ground, ranging from matching the intended distribution to meeting various criteria of independence.  If you mean all of the above--namely, that your version appears to behave like iid draws from a standard Normal--then please consult our threads on [testing random number generators.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=random+number+generator+test)

Comment: @whuber because I just learned the course -- simulation,my need may be just that check whether the cdf or pdf of my generated random variable is close to that of the desired random variable